# Django - INTEGRITY ERROR on column that no longer exists

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am getting this error:

```
IntegrityError at /register/
null value in column "total_daily_mission_progress" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (363, 0, 374, free, 0, null, unranked, 0, , odifj@gmail.com, 0, f, [], 0, {}, {}, t, null, null, null, null, null, {}, null, null, No phone number set, This user has not set a description yet., /static/images/profilepictures/defaultavatar.png, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, 0).
```

However, the column `total_daily_mission_progress` no longer exists in my `UserDetail` model. I deleted it a while ago and migrated. However, this issue comes up every time I try to create a new UserDetail model.

Why is this occuring? I don't have the `total_daily_mission_progress` anywhere in my code. And how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

Here is my output after running `python3 manage.py showmigrations --verbosity 2`

```
 [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:10)
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:10)
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:10)
auth
 [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:09)
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:11)
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:11)
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:11)
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:12)
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002 (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:12)
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:12)
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:12)
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:13)
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:13)
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:13)
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:13)
codera_main
 [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:14)
 [X] 0002_achievement_reward_alter_achievement_rarity (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:15)
 [X] 0003_achievement_num (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:15)
 [X] 0004_alter_achievement_name_alter_achievement_num (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:15)
 [X] 0005_alter_achievement_description_alter_achievement_name (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:16)
 [X] 0006_userdetail (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:17)
 [X] 0007_userdetail_skilllevel (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:17)
 [X] 0008_userdetail_plan (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:17)
 [X] 0009_userdetail_friends_alter_userdetail_skilllevel (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:17)
 [X] 0010_alter_userdetail_friends (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:18)
 [X] 0011_alter_userdetail_friends (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:18)
 [X] 0012_alter_userdetail_friends (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:18)
 [X] 0013_userstat (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:19)
 [X] 0014_usercode (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:19)
 [X] 0015_userreward (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:20)
 [X] 0016_remove_userstat_ribbons_remove_userstat_shards_and_more (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:20)
 [X] 0017_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:21)
 [X] 0018_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:21)
 [X] 0019_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:22)
 [X] 0020_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:22)
 [X] 0021_userstat_last_login (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:23)
 [X] 0022_userstat_monthly_streaks (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:23)
 [X] 0023_userdetail_user_spent (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:23)
 [X] 0024_remove_userdetail_user_spent_and_more (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:24)
 [X] 0025_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:24)
 [X] 0026_alter_usercode_levelscompleted (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:25)
 [X] 0027_remove_achievement_rarity_remove_achievement_reward_and_more (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:25)
 [X] 0028_achievement_achive_date (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:25)
 [X] 0029_alter_achievement_num (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:26)
 [X] 0030_rename_name_achievement_title (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:26)
 [X] 0031_delete_userreward (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:26)
 [X] 0032_userdetail_profilepicture (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:27)
 [X] 0033_alter_userdetail_profilepicture (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:27)
 [X] 0034_alter_userdetail_profilepicture (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:27)
 [X] 0035_alter_userdetail_profilepicture (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:27)
 [X] 0036_userstat_badges (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:28)
 [X] 0037_remove_userstat_badges_userreward (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:28)
 [X] 0038_remove_userdetail_profilepicture (applied at 2023-01-16 15:38:38)
 [X] 0039_remove_userdetail_friends (applied at 2023-01-16 15:40:34)
 [X] 0040_emailverified (applied at 2023-02-18 02:18:32)
 [X] 0041_remove_usercode_levelscompleted_and_more (applied at 2023-02-18 02:18:33)
 [X] 0042_userdetail_isverified (applied at 2023-02-18 02:18:33)
 [X] 0043_remove_usercode_user_remove_userreward_user_and_more (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:26)
 [X] 0044_alter_userdetail_levelscompleted (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:28)
 [X] 0045_userdetail_xp_alter_userdetail_league (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:28)
 [X] 0046_avatar (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:29)
 [X] 0047_alter_avatar_moves_unlocked (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:29)
 [X] 0048_alter_avatar_moves_unlocked (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:29)
 [X] 0049_userdetail_yesturday_diamonds (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:29)
 [X] 0050_remove_userdetail_yesturday_diamonds_and_more (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:30)
 [X] 0051_alter_userdetail_dimaond_progress (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:30)
 [X] 0052_rename_dimaond_progress_userdetail_diamond_progress (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:30)
 [X] 0053_userdetail_medal_progress (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:30)
 [X] 0054_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime_badge (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:31)
 [X] 0055_badge_image (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:32)
 [X] 0056_badge_popup_image (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:32)
 [X] 0057_alter_badge_badge_date_and_more (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:32)
 [X] 0058_alter_badge_badge_date (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:33)
 [X] 0059_alter_badge_badge_date (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:33)
 [X] 0060_alter_achievement_user_alter_badge_user (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:34)
 [X] 0061_userdetail_iscurrentlyactive (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:34)
 [X] 0062_avatar_accuracy_avatar_speed_alter_avatar_character_and_more (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:35)
 [X] 0063_avatar_rank (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:35)
 [X] 0064_alter_avatar_moves_unlocked_alter_avatar_rank (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:35)
 [X] 0065_alter_avatar_moves_unlocked (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:36)
 [X] 0066_avatar_strenght (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:36)
 [X] 0067_rename_strenght_avatar_strength (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:37)
 [X] 0068_userdetail_plan_purchase_date (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:37)
 [X] 0069_userdetail_checkout_id (applied at 2023-02-18 02:40:37)
 [X] 0070_alter_avatar_accuracy_alter_avatar_energy_and_more (applied at 2023-02-20 17:13:05)
 [X] 0071_guideemail (applied at 2023-02-22 23:52:59)
 [X] 0072_dailymission_userdetail_todays_daily_mission_and_more (applied at 2023-04-20 22:14:25)
 [X] 0074_alter_userdetail_totallearningtime (applied at 2023-04-24 13:54:24)
 [X] 0075_chest (applied at 2023-04-24 17:10:00)
 [X] 0076_userdetail_friends_list (applied at 2023-05-01 14:30:12)
 [X] 0077_friendrequest (applied at 2023-05-01 14:37:47)
 [X] 0078_friendrequest_date_sent (applied at 2023-05-01 22:54:00)
 [X] 0079_alter_friendrequest_date_sent (applied at 2023-05-01 23:00:54)
 [X] 0080_alter_friendrequest_date_sent (applied at 2023-05-02 01:07:36)
 [X] 0081_alter_userdetail_friends_list (applied at 2023-05-02 23:57:12)
 [X] 0082_remove_userdetail_friends_list (applied at 2023-05-02 23:59:09)
 [X] 0083_userdetail_friends_list (applied at 2023-05-02 23:59:27)
 [X] 0084_userdetail_first_name_userdetail_last_name_and_more (applied at 2023-05-09 20:39:01)
 [X] 0085_userdetail_description (applied at 2023-05-09 20:43:14)
 [X] 0086_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 21:41:22)
 [X] 0087_alter_userdetail_phone_number (applied at 2023-05-09 22:48:31)
 [X] 0088_alter_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 22:59:01)
 [X] 0089_remove_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 23:00:03)
 [X] 0090_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 23:00:13)
 [X] 0091_alter_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 23:08:33)
 [X] 0092_remove_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 23:09:17)
 [X] 0093_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-09 23:09:55)
 [X] 0094_remove_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:31:07)
 [X] 0095_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:31:20)
 [X] 0096_remove_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:34:04)
 [X] 0097_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:34:17)
 [X] 0098_remove_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:37:46)
 [X] 0099_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:41:59)
 [X] 0100_alter_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:46:03)
 [X] 0101_alter_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:48:49)
 [X] 0102_remove_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:49:22)
 [X] 0103_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 00:50:02)
 [X] 0104_alter_userdetail_profile_picture (applied at 2023-05-10 14:32:59)
 [X] 0105_alter_userdetail_league (applied at 2023-05-21 23:31:23)
 [X] 0106_userdetail_xp_progress_and_more (applied at 2023-05-28 23:28:41)
 [X] 0107_remove_userdetail_todays_daily_mission_completed_and_more (applied at 2023-05-29 16:14:45)
 [X] 0108_remove_userdetail_todays_daily_mission_and_more (applied at 2023-05-29 16:14:45)
 [X] 0109_userdetail_todaysdailymission_and_more (applied at 2023-06-01 14:39:33)
 [X] 0110_rename_todaysdailymissioncompelted_userdetail_todaysdailymissioncompleted (applied at 2023-06-01 14:39:33)
 [X] 0111_mainmission_alter_dailymission_num_and_more (applied at 2023-06-01 14:39:34)
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:05)
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:11)
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2022-12-29 19:39:29)
```

Comment: Can you add the migration name and its contents to your question and the output of `manage.py showmigrations <your_app_name_here> --verbosity 2` when run on the environment having the issue?

Comment: Sure, updating my question right now.

Comment: I have added the neccessary edits. Do you know why my error is occuring?

Comment: Looks like the migrations are all applied, might be worth running `manage.py migrate --check` to see if there are any changes missing in your migrations. Which DB are you using?

Comment: I'm on a Postgres SQL database. Running the command you provided gives me an output of `jahan@Jahans-MacBook-Pro-3 Codera % python3 manage.py migrate --check
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, codera_main, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Comment: I'm really perplexed as to why this issue is occuring. Other solutions online stated to delete my migrations and data, but I can't do this as this is a production level setup.

Comment: Someone may have faked the migration `manage.py migrate <app> --fake`, marking it as applied but not actually applying the changes? Were there other changes in this particular migration that were actually applied?

Comment: I have used `manage.py migrate <app> --fake` in the past, but I'm not sure if that's what is causing the error as I didn't have any other changes in that migration. Is there a way I can check or even undo the fake?

Comment: If you know which one was faked you can follow these steps: (I'm using 0005 as an example here) fake unapply the migrations to before the one you want to apply `migrate codera_main 0004 --fake`, then apply only the required migration `migrate codera_main 0005`, then fake apply all the following `migrate codera_main --fake`

Comment: I'm not sure which one was faked, I just know that I've faked migrations in the past. I'm not sure if thats a cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out, ended up using `python3 manage.py dbshell` and runnning the following command:

`ALTER TABLE_NAME FROM USERMODAL`